# Prove $T:V\rightarrow V$ is orthogonal if and only if $B$ is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ is orthogonal if $||T(f)||=||f||$ for all $f\in V$. Suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$, $T$ is a linear transformation, and $B$ is the $\mathcal{B}$-matrix of $T$. Show that $T$ is orthogonal if and only if $B$ is orthogonal.

So I'm trying to prove both directions. I start with assuming that $T$ is orthogonal, and try to derive that $B$ is orthogonal, but I'm not sure how to relate the fact that $||T(f)||=||f||$ to the fact that $B^TB = I$ (i.e. $B$ is an orthogonal matrix).

Similarly, going the other way, I'm having the same trouble. If I know $B^TB = I$, how do I know that $||T(f)||=||f||$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $v$ is the representation of $f$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}$, then $$\|f\|^2 = v^Tv\\ \|T(f)\|^2 = (Bv)^T(Bv) = v^T(B^TB )v.$$

Comment: So can we conclude that $B^TB = I$ since $||T(f)||^2 = ||f||^2$, since $T$ is orthogonal?

Comment: It's been some time since I studied this, but isn't this just a particular inner product? So this would only show a particular case.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 By assumption $\mathcal{B}$ is orthonormal and you can only check orthonormality with respect to the inner-product. So as long as $\mathcal{B}$ is orthonormal (with respect to the inner product) as assumed, this works.

Comment: The thing is you're assuming the matrix associated to the inner product (bilinear form) is the identity, but this may not be the case..

Comment: @hjhjhj57 In the basis $\mathcal{B}$, the matrix associated to the inner product is the identity.

Comment: Got it. I was getting all confused about the possibility of different signatures, but the existance of an orthonormal basis, as you say, solves this.